# Mostrar a idade em anos no php

Tags: php

Gostaria de pegar através da informação data, a idade da pessoa em anos:

Por exemplo:

06/09/1991 --> 24 anos
05/12/1998 --> 16 anos

Suponha que eu tenha essas datas no php

```
$data1 = new DateTime('19910906');
$data2 = new DAteTime('19981205');
```

Como eu poderia fazer para exibir as duas em anos?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Para comparar estas datas com a data atual utilize `new DateTime()` (para obter a data atual) com a função `diff`:

```
$data1 = new DateTime('19910906');
$data2 = new DateTime('19981205');

$idadeData1 = $data1->diff(new DateTime());
$idadeData2 = $data2->diff(new DateTime());

echo "Idade1: " . $idadeData1->y . " anos.";
// OUTPUT: Idade1: 24 anos.
echo "Idade2: " . $idadeData2->y . " anos.";
// OUTPUT: Idade2: 16 anos.
```

Veja no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/soS3uU).

Se fosse o caso de comparar as datas entre elas, você poderia fazer assim:

```
$data1 = new DateTime('19910906');
$data2 = new DAteTime('19981205');

$idade = $data1->diff($data2);
```

A função `diff` sempre vai retornar um objeto `DateInterval`:

```
object(DateInterval)[3]
  public 'y' => int 7
  public 'm' => int 2
  public 'd' => int 29
  public 'h' => int 0
  public 'i' => int 0
  public 's' => int 0
  public 'weekday' => int 0
  public 'weekday_behavior' => int 0
  public 'first_last_day_of' => int 0
  public 'invert' => int 0
  public 'days' => int 2647
  public 'special_type' => int 0
  public 'special_amount' => int 0
  public 'have_weekday_relative' => int 0
  public 'have_special_relative' => int 0
```

Então pra saber a idade é só acessar o índice `y`, com o operador `->`:

```
echo "A idade é de " . $idade->y . "anos."; 
// output: A idade é de 7 anos.
```

Veja no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/bYpFWm).

Comment: Era isso mesmo o que estava tentando fazer.

Answer (score 4):

> PHP >= 5.3

Exemplo usando `date_create(), date_diff()`:

```
# Orientado a objetos
$from = new DateTime('19910906');
$to   = new DateTime('today');
echo 'Idade1 ' . $from->diff($to)->y . " anos.";

# Procedural
echo 'Idade2 ' . date_diff(date_create('19981205'), date_create('today'))->y . " anos.";
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone.](https://ideone.com/bMNv5j)

> Versões anteriores:

```
function minhaIdade($date) {
    return intval(substr(date('Ymd') - date('Ymd', strtotime($date)), 0, -4));
}

echo 'Idade1 ' . minhaIdade('19910906') . ' anos';
echo 'Idade1 ' . minhaIdade('19981205') . ' anos';
```

Comment: Excelente!! e eu me matando com timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma de verificar a idade é subtrair o data atual pela outra data, supondo que a data esteja num formato correto (principalmente em `YYYY-MM-DD`, mas também pode ser utilizado outros formatos, como `YYYYMMDD`, `DD-MM-YYYY`, `MM/DD/YYYY`...):

```
echo floor((time() - strtotime('2000-10-01')) / (60 * 60 * 24 * 365));
// Resultado: 17
```

O `time` vai informar a data em formato Unixtime (ou seja em segundo desde 1970). O `strtotime` vai converter a string em Unixtime. O `floor` irá arredondar para baixo.

---

> Como está da documentação: "O uso desta função para operações matemáticas não é recomendado.", considere apenas como um outra opção, a resposta do [@gustavox](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/98857/15089) ainda é mais adequada.

Answer (score -3):

**Segue código comentado:**

```php
//adicionar as tags *PHP* **<?php** ao início e **?>** ao final do código
// substitua $pacientes['data']) pela data do nascimento ou pela primeira data, isto é, a mais antiga.

$data1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($pacientes['data'])); // data nascimento
$data2 = date("Y-m-d"); // data atual
$data2b = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 year')); // data daqui um ano
$data3 = $data2b - date('z', strtotime($data2)); // primeiro dia próximo ano
$data3b = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month')); // data daqui um mês
$data4 = $data3b - date('z', strtotime($data2)); // primeiro dia próximo mês

$d1_ano = date('Y', strtotime($data1));
$d2_ano = date('Y', strtotime($data2));
$r_ano = $d2_ano - $d1_ano;
$d1_dia = ($d1_ano*365.25)+date('z', strtotime($data1));
$d2_dia = ($d2_ano*365.25)+date('z', strtotime($data2)); // z = nª dia/ano

$r_dia = $d2_dia - $d1_dia; //dias vividos desde nascimento

$r_ano = $r_dia / 365.25; //anos vividos desde nascimento

$r_mes = $r_ano*30; // meses vividos desde nascimento

$f1_ano = date('Y', strtotime($data1));
$f2_ano = date('Y', strtotime($data3));
$rf_ano = $f2_ano - $f1_ano;
$f1_dia = ($f1_ano*365.25)+date('z', strtotime($data1));
$f2_dia = ($f2_ano*365.25)+date('z', strtotime($data1));

$rf_dia = $f2_dia - $f1_dia; // dias p/ próximo aniversário

$rf_ano = $rf_dia / 365.25; // idade (ano) atual 

$f_dia = ($r_dia - $rf_dia); // idade (dia) atual ou dias vividos este ano

$f_mes = $f_dia/30; // idade (mês) atual ou meses vividos este ano


if($rf_ano <= 1) {
    $concordancia_ano = "ano";
} else {
    $concordancia_ano = "anos";
};

if($f_mes <= 1) {
    $concordancia_mes = "mês";
} else {
    $concordancia_mes = "meses";
};


echo floor($rf_ano); echo " "; echo $concordancia_ano; echo " e "; echo floor($f_mes); echo " "; echo $concordancia_mes; echo ".";
```

B'H todo o conhecimento.