# Calcular idade do usuario pela data de nascimento cadastrada

Tags: php

Bom dia, tarde ou noite

Tenho a seguinte duvida: Como posso pegar a data de nascimento de um usuário cadastrado e fazer um cálculo para saber a idade dele hoje?

Se o usuário tiver menos de 18 anos por exemplo, não vai conseguir acessar a página de compra de certo produto (independente da idade o usuário precisa estar logado para conseguir acessar a pagina de compra).

O código no momento esta assim:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo'); // Hora oficial do Brasil.

include_once("../../pagina_de_cadastro/conecta_banco.php"); //Faz a conexao e seleciona o BD  
$select = "SELECT data_nasc FROM usuarios"; // Pegamos o conteudo do banco.  

$data_inicial = DateTime::createFromFormat('y/m/d', 'data_nasc'); //A data do banco deve esta no formato dia/mês/ano
$data_final = date('y/m/d'); // Salva o timestamp atual numa variável

$diferenca = $data_final - $data_inicial;

echo $diferenca;

if ($diferenca < 18) {
    echo '<p style="font-size:300px"> IDADE INSUFICIENTE </p>';
}
```

Comment: @fernandosavio acredito que o fato da linguagem ser diferente não se caracteriza como duplicata, não?

Comment: Falha minha, como tem a tag JS acabei me precipitando.

Comment: A duplicada é [desta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/98855/6333).

Answer (score 0):

Uma boa alternativa pra solucionar seu problema é a utilização do método diff da classe DateTime, ele recebe um objeto DateTime e retorna outro objeto contendo a diferença, no exemplo abaixo você acessa a diferença em anos, através do atributo y

```
function getAge($date){
        $from = new DateTime($date);
        $to   = new DateTime('today');
        return $from->diff($to)->y;
};

$age = getAge('1994-02-01');
```

Comment: Testei aqui e realmente funciona ,mas como posso chamar o campo com a data de nascimento do banco?

Comment: @EllysonVissotto bem vindo a comunidade meu amigo, procure resolver um problema de cada vez, e quando postar suas duvidas aqui procure enriquecer com detalhes da sua implementação, pra que possamos te ajudar.