# Vincular PHP com HTML e Calcular quantos anos e meses de idade

Tags: php, javascript, html, funções

Gostaria de sabe se é possível e como posso vincular esse html no php, adicionando a contagem de quantos anos e quantos meses a pessoa tem

Também queria uma função em php que mostre o nome quando enviado

tenho essa função pra o nome

```
  <?php
    
    if(isset($_post['enviar])){
         $nome= $_POST['nome'];
    
         echo *Seu nome é $nome !*;
    }

?>
```

HTML:

```
 <label for="input">Qual seu nome? </label>
         <br/> <br/>
        <input type="text" id=valor> 
        <input type="submit" onclick="capturar()" value="Enviar"> <br/>
        <p id="valorDigitado"></p>
     
        
    <label for="input">Qual a data do seu nascimento? </label> <br/> <br/>
        <input type="number" id="date" placeholder="data"> <br/>
        <input type="number" id="month" placeholder="mês"> <br/>
        <input type="number" id="year" placeholder="ano"> <br/>
        <br/> <br/>
    
        <button id="calc-btn">Calcular Idade</button>
    
        <p id="show-age"></p>
```

PHP se a data inserida for 09/01/1997

```
<?php
    //Data atual
    $dia = date (‘d’);
    $mes = date (‘m’);
    $ano = date (‘Y’);
    //Data do aniversário
    $dianasc = (’09′);
    $mesnasc = (’01′);
    $anonasc = (’1997′);
    //Calculando sua idade
    $idade = $ano - $anonasc;
    if ($mes < $mesnasc){
    $idade-;
    echo “$idade”;
    }
    elseif ($mes == $mesnasc and $dia <= $dianasc) {
    $idade-;
    echo “$idade”;
    }
    else{
    echo “$idade”;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Porque não fazer tudo em javascript? Vc sabe quando e pq usar um ou outro?

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Mostrar a idade em anos no php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/98855/mostrar-a-idade-em-anos-no-php)

Comment: tvdias, preciso fazer em php  :(

Comment: Mas as respostas da outra pergunta é em PHP, não?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa de um form, no action do form passe o nome do arquivo php (data.php). Os name dos campos input do html sao as chaves na variavel $_POST['nome'] e $_POST['data']. O e explode("-",$data); divide a data com base no "-" e retorna um array onde a posicao 0 é o ano, a 1 é mes e a 2 é o dia. Esse é o formato da data que vai do input para o php 2021-01-31.

data.php

```
<?php
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$data =  $_POST['data'];
$diasD = explode("-",$data);
//Data atual
$dia = date ('d');
$mes = date ('m');
$ano = date ('Y');
//Data do aniversário
$dianasc = ($diasD[2]);
$mesnasc = ($diasD[1]);
$anonasc = ($diasD[0]);
 //Calculando sua idade
 $idade = $ano - $anonasc;
if ($mes < $mesnasc){
    $idade -= 1;
    echo "$idade";
}
elseif ($mes == $mesnasc and $dia <= $dianasc) {
    $idade -= 1;
    echo "$idade";
}
else{
    echo "$idade";
}
?>
```

index.html

```
<form action="data.php" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome">
   <input type="date" name="data" id="data">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: muito bom, vlw!